# Explode does not work in PHP ajax file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-multiselect

**Here is my HTML code :**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group">
          <select id="horseDiscipline" name="horseDiscipline[]" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>
          <?php
          foreach($possibleDiscipline as $disciplineChoice)
          {
          ?>
               <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($disciplineChoice['disciplineName']) ; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($disciplineChoice['disciplineName']) ; ?></option>
         <?php
         }
         ?>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Rest of form-->
```

**Here is my jquery code** :

```
var formData = new FormData($('#addForm')[0]);
        $('#addButton').text('Création...');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'AJAXFOLDER/ajaxAddHorse',
            type: 'post',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
        });
```

**Here is my PHP code (ajaxAddHorse.php) :**

```
<?php

        //Récupération des disciplines du cheval

        $disciplines = "";

        $disciplinesTemp = explode(",", $_POST['horseDiscipline']);

        foreach ($disciplinesTemp as $names)
        {
            $disciplines = $disciplines + ' / ' + $names;
        }

        echo json_encode($disciplines);
```

**Here is what I get when I execute the code :**

[image]

**If I change my PHP file like this :**

```
<?php

        //Récupération des disciplines du cheval

        echo json_encode($_POST['horseDiscipline']);
```

**Here is what I get :**

[image]

So why the explode function does not work here? "," is the separator between the words like we can see on the second picture. However, when I try the explode function, the variable which should contain those words is empty...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do a `var_dump` of `$disciplinesTemp ` in your explode function

Comment: can you let us know what is the output of `var_dump($_POST['horseDiscipline']);exit;` in your code.check console for output  and paste in your question.Also use `console.log(data);` instead of `alert(data);`

Comment: You should use `console.log(var)` and not `alert(var)`

Comment: what you have does not seem to be a valid `json`

Comment: In php you do concatenation with `.` and not with `+`

Answer (score 1):

$disciplines = $disciplines + ' / ' + $names;

Instead of + it should be . since in php string concatenation is done by using . and not by +. Else everything is ok .

Comment: Yes, was a mistake sorry. Thank you. But even with this, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked :

Code :

```
    //Récupération des disciplines du cheval

    $disciplines = "";

    $disciplinesDump = var_dump($_POST['horseDiscipline']);

    echo json_encode($disciplinesDump);
```

Nothing is shown in the console logs.

But, if I write :

```
<?php

        //Récupération des disciplines du cheval

        echo json_encode($_POST['horseDiscipline']);
```

I have :
[image]

Hope it can help...

Edit :

**Solution was :**

```
foreach($_POST['horseDiscipline'] as $name){
    $disciplines = $disciplines . ' / ' . $name;
}

echo json_encode($disciplines);
```

Indeed, when a select tag has the multiple option in HTML, then the name should be name=name[]. So it returns an array, the solution is to read this array in php.

Thanks.